# Как узнать структуру базы данных Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: kotlin, firebase, firebase-database

Есть старый проект на гитхабе который не обновляется, хочу сделать форк. Проект работает с Firebase Realtime Database. Как узнать структуру базы чтобы воссоздать на своем фаербейсе ? проект https://github.com/5cr1p7/FoodsharingRus

В коде есть значения типа логин, пароль, никнейм, город итд.  Не очень хорошо разбираюсь в базах данных. Не могу понять как подключить новую базу к приложению.  Возможно воссоздать базу данных для приложения что бы она работала ?

Comment: тут, вроде как, одно из двух: либо структура описана по ссылке, либо нет. если первое, тогда непонятно, о чём тут спрашивать. а если второе, то ответа просто не существует.

Comment: структура не описана, там есть значения ( типа логин, пароль и тд) которые тянет с базы данных. Возможно воссоздать базу данных имея код только ?

Comment: да вы же сами только что и воссоздали: `там есть значения ( типа логин, пароль и тд)`. // вы, пожалуйста, конкретизируйте вопрос. прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: Сделал, спасибо. Не понимаю можно ли просто прописать в json эти значения или их нужно вложить  куда то ?